# Сколько хостов ansible обрабатывает за раз?

Tags: linux, ansible

Есть список хостов для которых нужно выполнить плейбук. Как узнать к скольким машинам коннектится ansible за раз и как поменять это значение (или через ключ или через переменную), если я точно знаю, что канал и сервера с которых вытягивается софт - выдержат?

UPD. Нашёл `serial`. Походу то, что [нужно](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html). Надо проверить.

Comment: Да, это именно то. )

Comment: Удалил слишком общие метки. Ansible и так про администрирование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## При запуске плейбука

В `ansible-playbook` есть ключ `--forks`, задающий количество одновременных обработчиков. Каждый обработчик работает с одним хостом.

```
  -f FORKS, --forks=FORKS
                        specify number of parallel processes to use
                        (default=5)
```

Чтобы запустить плейбук, например, одновременно на 20 хостах:

```
ansible-playbook mybook.yml --forks=20 ...
```

## Для конкретной задачи в плейбуке

Чтобы указать максимальное количество хостов, на которых одновременно может выполняться *конкретная задача* в плейбуке, добавьте к ней [ключ `serial`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html).

```
- name: test play
  hosts: webservers
  serial: 3
```

Вместо конкретного числа можно указать проценты:

```
- name: test play
  hosts: webservers
  serial: "30%"
```

### Делаем rolling release

Значением `serial` может быть список.
Например, мы хотим запустить плейбук сначала на одной машине, потом ещё на пяти.
Если всё хорошо, то на всех оставшихся машинах.

```
- name: test play
  hosts: webservers
  serial:
  - 1
  - 5
  - "100%"
```

Comment: Дефолт = 5. Норм. То, что нужно.

Comment: Автокад (и всё из автодеска, что есть), компас и мэпл кстати просто шикарно ставятся через ансибл. Я дичайше рад. Щас раскатывал Civil и последняя машина ставилась очень долго, хотя сеть была занята на 1/10. Потому и вопрос.

Comment: @donRumata btw, вы с chocolatey пробовали работать?

Comment: Свою репу не создавал, но работает через раз. То сервер недоступен, то ещё какая-то хрень. Не продакшн. А для своей репы надо сильно с пошиком загоняться. Не хочу пока калечить мозг. Можно кстати в том чате продолжить про шоколад, если есть желание.